# jQuery UI Autocomplete - Using Multiple Arrays & If-Statement for Output

Tags: arrays, jquery-ui, if-statement, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am having trouble modifying jQuery UI Autocomplete (Custom data and display). 
First, how to have the source option call more than one array. Second, to be able to detect which array the autocomplete result came from and use it in an if-statement.

I will try to be as clear as possible, as I am new at jQuery... any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

A more complete code example: http://codepen.io/seejaeger/pen/iqbke

---

**Overview**:

1. Declare & concatenate 2 local arrays as the source
2. Keep track of which array the suggestion results come from
3. Use an if-statement to display different outputs based on their parent array

**Each array item has the properties**: `value`, `label`, `desc`

I am paying special attention to `desc` because it is used as non-searchable data and
 provides the ability to output two different formatted results. See below:

**The First Array**

```
var funds = [
  {
    value: "fundtest",
    label: "Fund Name Test", //searchable
    desc: "(Ticker)", // non-searchable
  },
  {
    value: "fundtest2",
    label: "Fund Name Test 2", //searchable
    desc: "(Ticker)", // non-searchable
  }
];
```

**The Second Array**

```
var tickers = [
  {
    value: "tickertest",
    label: "(Ticker Test)", //searchable
    desc: "Fund Name", //non-searchable
  },
  {
    value: "tickertest2",
    label: "(Ticker Test)", //searchable
    desc: "Fund Name", //non-searchable
  }
];
```

**The Output**

**If** search suggestion comes from the `funds` array then, output:

```
item.label + " " + item.desc
```

**If** search suggestion comes from the `tickers` array, then output:

```
item.desc + " " + item.label
```

*Notice how they are swapped?*

The different HTML output structures will allow for both results
 to output to screen as: **'Fund Name (ticker)'**

---

**UPDATE**

Parts 1 & 2 are now solved.
Still having some issues with part 3.
Will finally post an answer once I solve it (unless someone magically chimes in).

*Big thanks to TR for his guidance.*

**View the latest edition of this work here:**
http://codepen.io/seejaeger/pen/iqbke

Comment: The only way to check which source is being used is to look the key up in the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key factors to solving this issue were:

- Add a key similar to `origin` (would be more elegant if a loop is used to append this key, I may add this in an update.)
- Concatenating both arrays into one so that it can be read as a `source`
- The `if-statement` within the `.data` function which weeds out which `origin` the autocomplete data stems from, and to output the result in a particular way based on that `origin`

Working demo: http://codepen.io/seejaeger/pen/iqbke

--

```
$(function() {

  var fund = [
    {
      value: "fundtest",
      label: "Fund Name Test", //searchable
      desc: "(ticker)", // non-searchable
      origin: "fund", // prefer to eliminate duplication
    },
    {
      value: "fundtest2",
      label: "Fund Name Test 2", //searchable
      desc: "(ticker)", // non-searchable
      origin: "fund", // prefer to eliminate duplication
    }
  ];

  var ticker = [
    {
      value: "tickertest",
      label: "(ticker test)", //searchable
      desc: "Fund Name", //non-searchable
      origin: "ticker", // prefer to eliminate duplication
    },
    {
      value: "tickertest2",
      label: "(ticker test 2)", //searchable
      desc: "Fund Name", //non-searchable
      origin: "ticker", // prefer to eliminate duplication
    }
  ];

  var suggest = fund.concat(ticker);

  $( "#project" ).autocomplete({  
    minLength: 2,  
    source: suggest, 
    focus: function( event, ui ) { 
      $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );
      return false;
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
      $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );
      $( "#project-id" ).val( ui.item.value );
      // $( "#project-description" ).html( ui.item.desc );
      // $( "#project-origin" ).html( ui.item.origin );

      return false;
    }
  })

 .data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
      if ( item.origin == 'fund') {
          return $( "<li>" )
          .append( "<a>" + item.label + " " + item.desc + "</a>" ) 
          .appendTo( ul );
      }
      else {
          return $( "<li>" )
          .append( "<a>" + item.desc + " " + item.label + "</a>" ) 
          .appendTo( ul ); 
          }
  }

});
```